# Firebase Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'FUIAuthDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using `Firebase 4.6.0`, `Xcode 9.1`, `Swift 4`.

When I implement the `FUIAuthDelegate` protocol and its required function `authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?)`, I still get a compile error "Type 'AppDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'FUIAuthDelegate'". Why?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

for me this was resolved by the adding method

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FirebaseAuth.User?, error: Error?) {
    print("did sign In")
}
```

instead of using

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {

}
```

Comment: I think I understand now. You and I probably already have our own `User` class, which confuses the compiler. By specifying `FirebaseAuth.User`, it clears up the confusion.